Generating a link to embed an OneDrive editable excel file without making it public
I have an Excel file in my OneDrive account. I'm also working on a web page.
I would like to embed that file in my web page using an iframe. I want to make it editable but not public.
That means: I need to generate a link to embed it using an iframe, but I don't want anybody else to be able to view/edit the excel file unless I share the file with them.
I tried with the /createLink endpoint of the Microsoft Graph API, but this creates a public link. Anyone with the link can view/edit the file and I don't want that.
Then I tried with the /preview endpoint of the Microsoft Graph API, but it doesn't work, the error says: "API not found".
Why is that? Is there another way to create an embed link to edit the excel file without making it public?
Thanks in advance
I tried the Microsoft graph API endpoints without success. Also tried with the share feature in OneDrive

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
